# strcpy when having char pointers in C

Tags: c, string, char

I have a simple doubt in `char` arrays. I have a structure:

```
struct abc {
char *charptr;
int a;
}

void func1()
{
    func2("hello");
}

void func (char *name)
{
    strcpy(abc.charptr, name); // This is wrong. 
}
```

This `strcpy` will result in a crash since I do not have any memory allocated to the `charptr`.
The question is : For `malloc`ing this memory, can we do

```
abc.charptr = (char *) malloc(strlen(name)); //?
strcpy(abc.charptr, name); // Is this (or strncpy) right ?
```

Is this right ?

Comment: You need to allocate `strlen(name)+1` because `strlen` does not count the `\0` byte that terminates a C-style string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
abc.charptr = malloc(strlen(name)+1); ?
strcpy(abc.charptr, name);
```

The return value of `strlen` doesn't include space for the null zero '\0'  at the end of the string.

You will also have to free your allocated memory at some point.

Comment: Generally speaking, don't cast the result of `malloc`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc.

Answer (score 7):

If you were to use `malloc()` you need to remember to make room for the null-terminator. So use `malloc(strlen(name)+1)` before calling `strcpy()`.

But in this case you should just use `strdup()` which does the allocation and copying in one go:

```
abc.charptr = strdup(name);
```

The memory returned by `strdup()` has been allocated with `malloc()` and hence must be disposed of with a call to `free()`.

Comment: I didn't realize strdup did this, ty!

Answer (score 1):

```
abc.charptr = (char *) malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
```

Note the +1, since you need space for the null terminator. Then strcpy() will be fine.

Comment: Generally speaking, don't cast the result of `malloc`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc.